# I have to filter data of categories which is in different component and cards are in different component how to link both to sort the cards

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to filter data of categories  which is in different component and cards are in different component how to link both to sort the cards using services
`Card ts file

```
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  products:any;

 constructor(private authService:AuthService) { 
}

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.authService.getProductList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.products=data 
     console.log(this.products)
    })
    this.products=this.authService.getdata()
  }
  details(product:any){
    this.authService.setdata(product)
  }
  
}
```

#### categories ts file

```
export class CategoriesListComponent implements OnInit {
productListData:any=[];
products:any=[];
  constructor(private authService:AuthService,private route:Router) { 
 
  }
  filter(category: string) {

    this.productListData = [];

    for (let i = 0; this.products.length > i; i++) {
      if (category == this.products[i].category) {
      this.productListData.push(this.products[i]);
    }

      }     
    console.log(this.productListData);  

    this.authService.setdata(this.productListData)
}

  category:any=[];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.getProductList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.products=data 
     console.log(this.products)
     for( let i=0;i<this.products.length;i++){
      console.log(this.products[i].category)
      let findcategory=this.category.find((value:any)=>value==this.products[i].category)
      if(findcategory==null){
        this.category.push(this.products[i].category)
      }
     }
     console.log("this.category",this.category)
  })
  }
}
```

#### service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getProductList() {

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:2000/api/getProductList');
  }

   data:any;
   getdata(){
    return this.data
   }
   setdata(value:any){
    return this.data=value
   }

}
```

need to link these 2 components so that i can render cards by filtering categories need solution how to give service components or is there any other way to call the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [subjects](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) from rxjs. Create a new subject in Card service and connect to it in Categories Component and filter in it.

Comment: i have to use subjects in card component or service file

Comment: Can u explain me briefly